# Python, sending email with special character in subject

Tags: python, email, encoding

I am sending email from Python (Django). The email host is 'smtp.gmail.com'. I am able to use special characters in the email subject when I use localhost. However, now that I am trying from the server (webfaction) I get an error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte..." In the email template I use hex codes, but they don't work for the subject (they aren't translated). What to do?

```
# coding=UTF-8
...

subject = "æøå"
c = {}
t_html = loader.get_template(template_html)
t_text = loader.get_template(template_txt) 
e = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, t_text.render(Context(c)), from_email, [to_email])
e.attach_alternative(t_html.render(Context(c)), "text/html")
e.send()
```

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/a/517974/230884 useful for my cases. Worth a look. I also agree with `mgibsonbr`. the `u` doesn't solve everything. Some other characters will fail.

Comment: @CppLearner What I meant was, just using `coding` **without** also using `u` does not always work. Anyway, if the environment does not support `coding` and/or the specified encoding, there's no way it can correctly read the source file. Better to use hex codes or `\uXXXX`.

Comment: @mgibsonbr I thought the opposite. Maybe it's just my environment. I've done as you suggested but that combination still didn't work. So at the end, I've to use the solution I linked above. I know so little about unicode (which is a shame lol). Hence, `useful for my cases` :) cheer.

Comment: @CppLearner you're right, the opposite is true too. See my updated answer. And don't worry, unicode is a tricky subject, I'm working with it for years and still have a lot to learn (normalization, for instance, is unbeknownst to me).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Python 2, I'd suggest prepending your string with `u`:

```
subject = u"æøå"
```

(I know the `coding` "magic comment" is supposed to handle that automatically, but from experience I can say it does not always work)

**Update:** for future reference, it's also important to ensure the production environment supports the same encoding used on development. It should be fine with `UTF-8` (it's supported everywhere), but if you were to edit your source files under Windows (`Cp1252`) and then deploy in a UNIX server, the Python interpreter might not be able to read them, regardless of the presence of `coding`.

Comment: Nice, that did the trick! (I can accept your answer in 5 minutes)